# Exclude data from array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON file which come from a URL

```
{
"eur": {
    "code": "EUR",
    "alphaCode": "EUR",
    "numericCode": "978",
    "name": "Euro",
    "rate": 0.92014592622619,
    "inverseRate": 1.0867841409692,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"tnd": {
    "code": "TND",
    "alphaCode": "TND",
    "numericCode": "788",
    "name": "Tunisian Dinar",
    "rate": 2.5199297392244,
    "inverseRate": 0.39683646112601,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"try": {
    "code": "TRY",
    "alphaCode": "TRY",
    "numericCode": "949",
    "name": "Turkish Lira",
    "rate": 3.5735711390353,
    "inverseRate": 0.27983212341198,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"gbp": {
    "code": "GBP",
    "alphaCode": "GBP",
    "numericCode": "826",
    "name": "U.K. Pound Sterling",
    "rate": 0.78192136197811,
    "inverseRate": 1.2789009849663,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"cad": {
    "code": "CAD",
    "alphaCode": "CAD",
    "numericCode": "124",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "rate": 1.3511687609782,
    "inverseRate": 0.7401,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"jod": {
    "code": "JOD",
    "alphaCode": "JOD",
    "numericCode": "400",
    "name": "Jordanian Dinar",
    "rate": 0.70943909789052,
    "inverseRate": 1.409564264182,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"egp": {
    "code": "EGP",
    "alphaCode": "EGP",
    "numericCode": "818",
    "name": "Egyptian Pound",
    "rate": 18.190428713858,
    "inverseRate": 0.054973965469992,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
},
"ils": {
    "code": "ILS",
    "alphaCode": "ILS",
    "numericCode": "376",
    "name": "Israeli New Sheqel",
    "rate": 3.649,
    "inverseRate": 0.27404768429707,
    "date": "Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:30:00 GMT"
}
```

}

I made a php page to insert the array into a database, here is the code:

```
<?php
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tabs", "pass", "tabs"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
      $filename = "usd.json";
      $data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
      $array = json_decode($data, true); 

      foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
      {    
       $query .= "INSERT INTO PrBlack(code, ncode, rate, date) VALUES ('".$row["code"]."', '".$row["numericCode"]."', '".$row["rate"]."', '".$row["date"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 

      }
      if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{
 echo '<h3>Imported Data</h3><br />';

      }

      ?>
```

It is working fine, but what if I want to remove the "eur" array only? What should I do?

Comment: after $array = json_decode($data, true);  why don't you unset "eur" like: unset($array["eur"]);

Comment: It works! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just unset($array["eur"]) after decode the array:

```
<?php
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tabs", "pass", "tabs"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
      $filename = "usd.json";
      $data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
      $array = json_decode($data, true); 
      unset($array["eur"]);
      foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
      {    
       $query .= "INSERT INTO PrBlack(code, ncode, rate, date) VALUES ('".$row["code"]."', '".$row["numericCode"]."', '".$row["rate"]."', '".$row["date"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 

      }
      if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{
 echo '<h3>Imported Data</h3><br />';

      }

      ?>
```

Comment: if it worked for you so hope you will accept this answer by tick as right answer

Comment: It's a bad practise to modify raw input. It's better to ignore irrelevant things.

Comment: @ modsfabio you mean by your case every time you will check the condition if($currency == "eur") continue; ?? if the array has more than 1000 key so every time you want to execute this condition?

Comment: It's not a big performance problem. Anyway, maybe any time soon he wants to use the raw input later in the code but already deleted some data from it...

Comment: @modsfabio and also unset() to an array element is not an bad practise

Comment: I'm not saying unset() is a bad practise, but modifying raw user input is.

Comment: @modsfabio if the OP question is about to remove an array so unset() is the best solution and as he mentioned to remove the array so that mean that array is worthless for him

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $currency=>$row)
{
  if($currency == "eur") continue;

  //DO SOMETHING WITH THE REST
}
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)